# How to block ports from public and allow ports within Vnet in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, network-security-groups

I've setup a site-to-point VPN in Azure. 
I want to allow ports 3389, 22, 5432, 8080 for users that logs in using the VPN client and at the same allow only port 8080 at the public IP for this VM. These configs can be done at the NSG
How can I achieve this?

In the VM/Networking tab, I can see NSG attached to a subnet and another NSG attached to the NIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a rule allowing 8080 from the internet, the NSG default rule already allows communication on the virtualnetwork tag which includes VPN gateway routes

[image]

Comment: lol. Tat just went right over my head. Thanks man.
I just deleted all the inbound restrictions on the NIC NSG.
Allowed Vnet access. By default all the public port requests are rejected due to Deny rule in the NIC. 
For making any ports public I just had to add exception for making it public at the NIC NSG.
Thanks for the help man.
You smawt. I appreciate you :P

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, wherever possible try not to assign NSGs to NICs - Not that it makes for *bad* practice it just makes for greater management difficulty.  Though in some very tight security scenarios this may be necessary.

Your point-to-site VPN will be served by a VPN Gateway, and clients will be issued an IP address from the client address pool.

In your scenario, you will need to create an inbound rule to allow connections from the VPN clients to the target VM's internal IP address in any and all NSGs which are applied to:

- The Gateway subnet
- The subnet of the VM's NIC
- The VM's NIC

If you don't have an NSG applied to the Gateway subnet, you can leave it as it is.

You will need to get the client address pool from the VPN gateway and use the CIDR-notated network address to populate the source CIDR range.  Example below:

---

[image: NSG Rule]

---

Ensure that you have assigned an appropriate priority to the rule, such that it is processed before any deny action rules which may take precedence.

You may wish to exclude 8080 from this rule, and instead create a separate one which allows any source address access to it.  This rule would need to exist on the subnet and NIC NSGs.

Comment: So basically are we just configuring the NSG of the NIC facing the public internet to respond to this IP range?

Comment: Client VPN traffic goes through your Gateway Subnet -> VM subnet -> VM NIC.  So you should have this rule in place in any NSGs which are applied to any of these three locations.  You can use IP Flow Verify in Azure Network Watcher to test the flow which will highlight any NSGs which are blocking or permissive.

Comment: The NSG at NIC is what stops the public ip traffic right?  We can set Nsg at all those levels but it comes down to ip filtering kept at NIC to stop public traffic right? If tats the case then is there any advantage of using a vpn? Sorry for asking all this, cus it doesnt make any sense to spend and setup the vpn config if tats the case.